# DB Tables which are in 3NF or 4NF but not in DKNF

Tags: rdbms, database-normalization, 3nf

Are there examples of Relational tables which are in 3NF or 4NF but
not in Domain Key Normal Form?

Answer (score 1):

Edit, Aug 2018 after 9 years

DKNF is the ultimate state of database normalisation after all previous normal forms have been eliminated

```
  1NF -> 2NF -> 3NF -> BCNF -> 4NF -> 5NF -> 6NF/DKNF
```

The 6NF/DKNF question (Fagin vs Date) is out of scope here

So the question doesn't make sense because any design that is "only" in 3NF or 4NF won't be DKNF (or 6NF)

Most folk don't design past BCNF unless you have particularly complex relationships.

New link: https://www.tutorialride.com/dbms/database-normalization.htm

Comment: 4NF, 5NF & 6NF are not special cases of DKNF (or vice versa) so it makes no sense to say one is "between" another & DKNF. Also the (normalization) "Summary" link is full of errors although not re DKNF & the Wikipedia article is garbage after the initial definition. (And the first link is dead.) Also please do not post just links as an (alleged) answer, posts should be self-contained.

Comment: @philipxy thanks for feedback on how to post answers, on a 9 year old answer. But now you've highlighted it I'll explain more. I've no idea why you object to "between" either

Comment: This answer is wrong. As I already said, "4NF, 5NF & 6NF are not special cases of DKNF". The new link is wrong re DKNF, saying "3NF, 4NF, 5NF and BCNF are special cases of the DKNF". (Also about other things including definitions of 4NF & 5NF.) Eg a 6NF base relation could be restricted to having 2 tuples, hence not be in DKNF. DKNF is a special case of (implies) 5NF; but not of 6NF. [ON DK/NF NORMAL FORM](https://web.archive.org/web/20120406123712/http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/621935.htm)

Comment: @philipxy Not sure where you're going with this now. Your link can be summarised as Date saying Fagin was wrong. I have answered the question, in that a design normalised to at most 4NF is highly likely to be not in DKNF unless very simple. Why not add your own answer?

Comment: In my link it is clear that Date does not say Fagin is wrong about anything & just clarifies what Fagin said. This question can be simply answered & DKNF simply explained & related to the JD-removing NFs (on the sequence through 5NF to 6NF) just using the definitions of the NFs. But not by reproducing the "serious nonsense published on this topic in the trade press and elsewhere". I don't know why you wonder where I'm going with my comment; re this answer & previous versions & this one's link & previous links I have consistently just given some ways that they are wrong. Yeah, I should answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Domain Key Normal Form is not an enforceable normalization step.  DKNF is "If every table has a single theme, then all functional dependencies will be logical consequences of keys. All data value constraints can then be expressed as domain constraints."  In other words, if every constraint on the relation is a logical consequence of the definition of keys and domains, then the relation is in DKNF.

DKNF is mistakenly referred to as Sixth Normal Form (6NF) by some in the research community, but it is technically incorrect.  CJ Date covers this in detail, and this [On DK/NF Normal Form](https://web.archive.org/web/20120406123712/http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/621935.htm) article is where I first learned about DKNF and understood its properties.